# Why does my VPS have a default domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, vps

I have purchased a new VPS with a dedicated IP address. I noticed that its hostname is something like vmi223344.example.net. I then was able to access the Apache server by browsing http://vmi223344.example.net. How does my VPS have a domain while neither bind-utils nor named are installed? How does this domain name resolve to the IP address?
I know that my computer does domain lookups, but where is that information stored? How does it work that soon after purchasing the VPS, the server is accessible via the named domain instead of IP?
More importantly, now that the VPS has a default domain name, can I add another domain names to it (using `named` by making the VPS a name server for itself)  and remove the default one?

Comment: Is `example.net` yours, or your host's? Who handles your DNS?

Comment: @ceejayoz, example.net is not mine. I don't know whose is that, because I have bought the service from let's say serverfault.com, not example.com. That's also my question, who (which computer) handles that domain name translation?

Comment: @codezombie Sounds like your host automatically sets up a record for every VPS, on a domain they own and manage. If so, their DNS servers are responsible for its management and resolution, not yours. Not uncommon - every new AWS EC2 instance gets a `amazonaws.com` subdomain automatically assigned, for example.

Comment: Would have been a lot easier to answer if you had mentioned the VPS provider and domain, and obfuscated your hostname.  Anyway if you know the DNS name, why not try something simple and do `whois dnsname.org`.  It seems likely that it is owned by your VPS provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How on earth my VPS have a domain while neither bind-utils nor named are installed?

From the sounds of things, your VPS provider, when they create a VPS for you, also create (likely in an automatic fashion) a subdomain (of a domain they own/control for this purpose) in *their* DNS systems that points to the new VPS's IP address. Their DNS servers are sending the record, so it doesn't matter one bit that you don't have DNS setup on your VPS - it's not consulted for this record at all, anyways.

This is pretty common - any new AWS EC2 instance gets one automatically on a `amazonaws.com` subdomain, for example.

> More importantly, now that the VPS has a default domain name, can I add another domain names to it (using named by making the VPS a name server for itself) and remove the default one?

Yes, you can have the VPS handle any number of other domains. (I tend to recommend outsourcing DNS to something like AWS Route53, but you're welcome to run `named` if you really want.)

You may not be able to remove the DNS record your VPS provider has set up (feel free to ask 'em). You can, however, set a "default virtualhost" on the server so that subdomain (and any other unknown ones your server isn't specifically expecting) goes to an error page or something of your choosing.

Comment: I think you should include an answer to the last part of the question: "can I add another domain names to it (using named by making the VPS a name server for itself) and remove the default one?"

Comment: @kasperd Looks like that was added after my answer. Doing now.

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote your answer again. Btw. it was added to the question about 20 minutes before your answer, but it's quite plausible you hadn't seen that update before answering.